# Python- Printing sequence of integers separated by commas

Tags: python, string, printing

```
L=input().split(' ')
for i in L:
  c=float(i)
  print(int(c), sep=",")
```

A sequence of numbers separated by space is to be accepted from user, the numbers are converted to the greatest integer less than or equal to the number and then printed.
I wanted to print the output on same line, but my code doesn't work

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Indent your print statement

Comment: @randomer64 they will also need to change `sep` to `end` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through the list, change to float and put it into variable `c`. That loop is essentially meaningless. After that loop `c` contains the last value in the iteration. Just print the result at once:

```
L=input().split(' ')
all_ints = map(int, L)
print(*all_ints, sep=',')
```

Or using `str.join`:

```
print(','.join(map(str, all_ints)))
```

Or using a loop:

```
for i in all_ints:
    print(i, end=',')
```

To get them all as `float`s you can use `map` as well:

```
all_floats = list(map(float, L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you:

```
L = input().split(' ')
for i in L:
  c = float(i)
  print(int(c), end=" ")
```